# Is there a way to target an item based on the closest attribute which contains an integer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, scrolltop

Here's the basic idea of what I'm trying to accomplish, I have a list...

```
<ul>
<li position="400">Item 1</li>
<li position="510">Item 2</li>
<li position="590">Item 3</li>
<li position="614">Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

And what I would like to do is select the closest item based on a number.

If our random number was 490, it would add the class "selected" to the list Item 2.

But I don't know how to do this, or if it's even possible... I'm doing this for navigation purposes, so...

```
var position = $(window).scrollTop();
```

then on keypress, select list item with the position attribute closest to the "position" variable. Am I making sense?

If anyone could help walk me through this I'd appreciate it, I'm lost

Comment: How about 520? do you want it to select 510? or 590? is the selection always forward closest? or it can be backwards too?

Comment: Well depending on the situation I'd like to do it either backward or forwards (based on up arrow or down arrow), however if someone can just explain how to do it one way I'm sure I can figure it out there from there. I just don't have the foggiest idea how this can be accomplished, aka selecting an item with an attribute that has the closest value to a specific variable.

Comment: see updated answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9748013/880434

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function selectClosest(val){
var diffs = [];
$("li[position]").each(function(){
    diffs.push(Math.abs(parseInt($(this).attr("position"))-val));
});
$("li[position]").eq(diffs.indexOf(Math.min.apply( Math,diffs))).css("font-weight","bold");
}

selectClosest(551);
```

Comment: ooooh awesome, this looks like the type of thing I need. I'm going to tweak with it a bit and get back to you. Thanks a bunch of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could do the binary search on an array of positions:
just create an array of positions, sorted by "position" attribute, and do the binary search:

```
var positions = [];
$("[position]").sort(function (a, b) {
    return $(a).attr("position") - $(b).attr("position")
})
.each(function () {
    positions.push(parseInt($(this).attr("position")));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the solution on this post [Formal way of getting closest values in array in Javascript, given a value and a sorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431259/formal-way-of-getting-closest-values-in-array-in-javascript-given-a-value-and-a) you could do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/phFUq/

```
var num = 600, // scroll number
    $li = $('li'),
    pos = [];

$li.each(function() {
    pos.push($(this).attr('position'));
});

function sortfunc(a, b) { // To sort `pos` array
    return a - b;
}
var getClosestValues = function(a, x) {
    var lo, hi;
    for (var i = a.length; i--;) {
        if (a[i] <= x && (lo === undefined || lo < a[i])) lo = a[i];
        if (a[i] >= x && (hi === undefined || hi > a[i])) hi = a[i];
    };
    return [lo, hi];
};

$('li[position=' + 
    getClosestValues(pos.sort(sortfunc), num)[0] + 
    ']').toggleClass('red'); // Or whatever...
```