# Change number to the closest from the list of numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input, numbers

I have a list of numbers. I have a input type='text' form where someone can write any number.
But I want this number that he entered to change to the closest one from my list.

For example my list contains these numbers: 1, 5, 10, 12, 19, 23, 100, 400, 999. There is no sense in this sequence, don't even try to figure it out :).
And also I have the simplest form:

```
<form id="myform">
<input type="text" id="mytext">
</form>
```

And if person writes 105 in my input, his number changes to 100; if he writes 18, he gets 19 and so on...

Does someone have any ideas? I think that it can be done in javascript (maybe jquery) but I couldn't write or find a working one...

Comment: What is the form/type of your list, an `li`, an object or an array ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431259/formal-way-of-getting-closest-values-in-array-in-javascript-given-a-value-and-a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach is:

```
var precast = [1, 5, 10, 12, 19, 23, 100, 400, 999];

function recast(el, arr) {
        var val = parseInt(el.value, 10);
    if ((!el || !arr) && val >= arr[0]) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (arr[i] > val) {
                var d = arr[i] - val;
                return arr[i-1] + d >= val ? arr[i-1] : arr[i];
            }
        }
    }
}

document.getElementById('mytext').onblur = function(){
    this.value = recast(this, precast);
};
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/nZVHn/1/).

Comment: Just in case somebody also has a simple problem: I also added a line "else if (arr[len-1] < val){return arr[len-1];}" to this function for a case when person enters a a number that is bigger then the biggest one in the list

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
var theArray = [ 1, 5, 10, 12, 19, 23, 100, 400, 999 ];
var goal = parseInt(("#mytext").val());
var closest = null;

$.each(theArray, function(){
  if (closest == null || Math.abs(this - goal) < Math.abs(closest - goal)) {
    closest = this;
  }
});
```