# Finding the index position of the nearest value in a Fortran array

Tags: fortran, binary-search

I have two sorted arrays, one containing factors (array `a`) that when multiplied with values from another array (array `b`), yields the desired value:

```
a(idx1) * b(idx2) = value
```

With `idx2` known, I would like find the `idx1` of `a` that provides the factor necessary to get as close to `value` as possible.

I have looked at some different algorithms ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4431347/943773), for example), but I feel like they would all be subject to potential problems with floating point arithmetic in my particular case.

Could anyone suggest a method that would avoid this?

Comment: Are the arrays sorted? If yes I would use the referenced method.

Comment: They are sorted. Updated question to reflect that. Thanks.

Comment: It is not clear how binary search is connected to floating point problems. Are you saying the floating point problems would not exist for a linear search? Is your problem with binary search, or floating point arithmetic? You might need to include more detail about the floating point problems you are trying to avoid.

Comment: I was thinking that to do the search, I would require performing conditional statements to "near" values derived from `a` * `b`, which I thought could lead to problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this expression

```
minloc(abs(a-value/b(idx2)))
```

will return the the index into `a` of the first occurrence of the value in `a` which minimises the difference.  I expect that the compiler will write code to scan all the elements in `a` so this may not be faster in execution than a search which takes advantage of the knowledge that `a` and `b` are both sorted. In compensation, this is much quicker to write and, I expect, to debug.